# How to classify sentence and Non-sentence type out of word sequence?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have bunch of lines and they can be categorized in 2 types.

Types of word Sequence:

1. Its a valid English sentence:

   Exp: - As a committed **Software Engineer** with over 5 years of
   experience on Microsoft Technologies and Business Intelligence
   tools.
2. Not an valid English sentence(just word sequence):
   Examples:

   - Client  :    PMP Auto Components
   - HTML , Cascading Style Sheets ,Java Script , JSP
   - Organization  :  Satyam Computer Services Ltd. ,    | ? | Designation  :  Software Engineer | ? | Duration  :  03 / 2006    03
     / 2010 | ? |
   - SLC - STC Merit Certified - 2006  Satyam Computer Services Ltd.

I am using python for machine learning task.i can use POS tags as feature for classification by NLTK. Which  algorithm can be applied in  this problem ?

Update:
Which features should be utilized for prediction of whether its a sentences are not ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the treetaggerwrapper:
[Reathedocs of TreetaggerWrapper](https://treetaggerwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage)

From the docs it should be easy to use:

```
import pprint   # For proper print of sequences.
import treetaggerwrapper
#1) build a TreeTagger wrapper:
tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en')
#2) tag your text.
tags = tagger.tag_text("This is a very short text to tag.")
pprint.pprint(treetaggerwrapper.make_tags(tags))
```

Checking if the sentance holds a noun (tag `NN`), a verb (tag `VBZ`) and a proper sentence punctuation (tag `SENT`)